# Reverse geocoding API and the city labels with OpenStreetMaps

Tags: openstreetmap, api, reverse-geocoding

I have troubles to get the typically displayed city names in the maps with reverse geocoding API like OpenStreetMap. See for example Salisbury, UK:

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/reverse.html?lat=51.06913&lon=-1.79077&zoom=10

Even though the coordinates are in the middle of the Salisbury city and the "zoom" is 10 for cities, the API do not reply any information that it is Salisbury. Moreover, when I "zoom" in the details to obtain "town" level information, the results still do not have anything about "Salisbury". The "zoom" level 13 gives me e.g. Milford as the result.

The free API of BigDataCloud.com gives me Salisbury for the coordinates and also mostly the names of the places I need, yet instead of a name "London" it gives me "Greater London".

What am I doing wrong that I'm unable to get the place labels as seen in the maps without "Greater", "municipal", "administrative", "City of" or whatever additional stuff in the name?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76467240/reverse-geocoding-api-and-the-city-labels-with-openstreetmaps